# How to broadcast two access points?

Tags: hostapd

How do I broadcast two access points with two WiFi cards with hostapd? Most tutorials don't work since udhcpd doesn't work with two access points.

Comment: Please don't cross post : http://serverfault.com/questions/698998/how-to-broadcast-two-access-points-with-hostapd

Answer (score 0):

dnsmasq can bind to separate network interfaces and provide a mix of address ranges as a dhcp server using its dhcp-range option a really good explanation is at https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/dnsmasq

It can also really simplify any DNS look up services you might want to provide